# why does PhotoCamera need a VideoBrush?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

When using the PhotoCamera one must create an instance of the PhotoCamera as well as a VideoBrush - and then assign that PhotoCamera instance to the source of the VideoBrush instance before the camera can be initialized.  example:

```
PhotoCamera camera;
VideoBrush brush;

camera = new PhotoCamera();
camera.Initialized += CameraInitialized;

brush = new VideoBrush();
brush.SetSource(camera);
```

The VideoBrush is clearly useful in scenarios where the developer wishes to create a viewfinder for the camera video stream by associating the VideoBrush instance with the brush of a visual object like a Canvas.Background or Rectangle.Fill.  However, when that is not the case, requiring the developer to still go through the motions of creating a VideoBrush seems somewhat random at first glance.

So two questions, why does the PhotoCamera always need to be associated with the VideoBrush?

What is the performance impact associating with attaching the PhotoCamera to a VideoBrush?  Specifically how are calls to GetPreviewBuffer(Argb|Y|YCbCr) impacted by the associated VideoBrush?

Thanks!

PS. hopefully this doesn't come off as pointed in anyway, I'd just like to have a better understanding of why this requirement exists - and how it impacts performance.

PPS. the improvements in the WP7 SDK for Mango are amazing - I'm looking forward to seeing what people come up with now that access to the sensors have been opened up.

Comment: Well, why not?  Do you want to use the camera w/o showing the picture on-screen?  Have you tried operating the camera w/o a brush?

Comment: I wasn't explicitly clear here, but no, the only role of the VideoBrush in my application is to trigger the initialization of the PhotoCamera.  My visuals are derived from the data in the PreviewBuffer + image processing.

Answer (score 0):

In mango you simply have two options, either do as you suggested above to use a frame in your app (a Video Frame) to take pictures, essentially grabbing a single frame from the video brush.
Or you can use the old NoDo method of using the PhotoChooser Task, which will launch the framework camera app separately and return an image.

Obviously pro's and cons of both methods so just choose the one that suit you.